# Unable to install php7 on fedora

Tags: php, fedora, dnf

I am running Fedora 24 on my development workstation. Eclipse needs php executables that match those on the server (Centos).

I have installed the remi-release repository and followed the instructions at https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/12/05/Install-PHP-7.1-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora:

```
# wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/remi-release-24.rpm
# dnf install remi-release-24.rpm
# dnf install dnf-plugins-core
# dnf config-manager --set-enabled remi-php71
# dnf update
```

When I invoke php there is no php:

```
# php -v
bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

Where are the executables located? There does not seem to be any php installed.

Help!

Comment: Update: enabled repository like so:
# dnf config-manager --set-enabled remi
then:
# dnf install php70
and it seemed to install a whole load of stuff, php70, php70-php-cli, php70-php-cinnamon, php70-php-json, php70-runtime.
However, I still get:
# php -v
bash: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remi repository provides various PHP Versions for Fedora.

- Versions older than default base version are only available as Software Collections (php70 way suggested by @Peter
- Newer versions are provided both as base packages and SCL

See the [configuration wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

But as you are running Fedora 24 which is now EOL, I heartly recommend you to upgrade to a supported version:

- Fedora 25 provides PHP 7.0
- Fedora 26 provides PHP 7.1
- Fedora 27 will provide PHP 7.1
- Fedora 28 will provide PHP 7.2

If you are interested in running multiple versions, you can read [My PHP Workstation](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation)

Comment: Thanks, Remy. There is a glitch in my installation which refuses to upgrade from F24. So upgrading would involve a clean installation which is too time consuming for me at this point. I will keep this information tucked away. Cheers, Peter.

Comment: Hi Remy, one quick question. I have upgraded my CentOS server to php 7.1.9 to get it as close as I can to the version I have on my workstation (7.1.10). Xdebug stopped working. I cannot install it because: Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.6.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64, but there is no php 5.6 installed. If I try to yum remove php-common-5* it tells me there is no such package. Also I can't find php 7.1 anywhere. It works, but I can't find  it! Cheers, Peter

Comment: 1st disable webtatic which cause such conflicts, then follow the Wizard instruction from above answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in my comment. It was necessary to do this:

```
# dnf config-manager --set-enabled remi
# dnf install php70
```

Then I put a symbolic link from /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/php70